# R searching for information within column

Tags: arrays, r

I have two tables. Which have the kind of formatting shown below. One of it is table A as such:

```
students|Test Score
A       |  100
B       |   81
C       |   92
D       |   88
```

Another table B I have looks like this:

```
Class | Students
1     | {A,D}
2     | {B,C}
```

I would like to perform some sort of manipulation in R where by I can search for the students listed in the array under the column in table B from table A and tabulate the scores into the following format:

```
    Class | Students | Mean Score
    1     | {A,D}    |   94
    2     | {B,C}    |   86.5
```

Is there any formula which I can use to do the searching and then merge those results by some manipulation in R?

Comment: What is the class of the "Students" column in the second table? A vector or a list?

Comment: it is actually a factor as the source file was in this format for that column: "{A,D}" etc

Answer (score 4):

A simple way using base R:

```
df2$mean_score <- sapply(df2$Students, function(x, df) {
                        students_vec <- unlist( strsplit(gsub("[{}]","", x),  split=",") )
                        mean(df[which( df$students %in% students_vec ), "Test Score"] )
       }, df = df1)

df2
#  Class Students mean_score
#1     1    {A,D}       94.0
#2     2    {B,C}       86.5
```

We apply over over the students column in `df2` and create a vector of the students we want. Then we just subset `df1` to those students and take the mean. Note that this is assuming your `df2$Students` data comes as a character string.

**Data:**

```
df1 <- structure(list(students = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), `Test Score` = c(100L, 
81L, 92L, 88L)), .Names = c("students", "Test Score"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Class = 1:2, Students = c("{A,D}", "{B,C}")), .Names = c("Class", 
"Students"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4):

A similar solution to @MikeH:

```
B$MeanScore <- sapply(strsplit(gsub("[{}]","", B$Students), split=","),
       function(x) mean(A$Test.Score[A$Students %in% x]))
```

Which gives:

```
#  Class Students MeanScore
#1     1    {A,D}      94.0
#2     2    {B,C}      86.5
```

Comment: Nice, more condensed! `sapply`ing over the data in my answer is repetitive since `strsplit` returns a list...

Comment: This is a nice approach.  If you instead change `df1` to only have one column with the `row.names` equal to `c("A","B","C","D")` you can use subsetting like so: `df1 <- structure(list(Test.Score = c(100L, 81L, 92L, 88L)), .Names = "Test.Score",row.names = c("A","B","C","D"), class = "data.frame")`.... Now, we have `sapply(strsplit(gsub("[{}]","", df2$Students),","), function(x) mean(df1[x, ]))`.  This allow you to avoid using `%in%`.

Comment: Hi, just an addition to the function above is there another method in which I confined the mean of test score for students in X and add a second condition example the year in which the test is taken matches the year of class.

Answer (score 2):

A  `dplyr` and `tidyr` solution that uses `unnest` to break apart and `paste` with the `collapse` option to assemble. Test data from @Ben Fasoli

```
A <- read.csv(text = 'Students,Test Score
A,  100
B,   81
C,   92
D,   88', stringsAsFactors = F)

B <- read.csv(text = 'Class, Students
1,"{A,D}"
2,"{B,C}"', stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
mutate(Students = gsub('\\{|\\}', '', Students))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
B %>% 
  unnest(Students = strsplit(Students, ",")) %>%
  inner_join(A) %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarize(Students = paste0("{", paste(Students, collapse=","), "}"), mean_score = mean(Test.Score))

  #     Class Students mean_score
  #     <int>    <chr>      <dbl>
  #   1     1    {A,D}       94.0
  #   2     2    {B,C}       86.5
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more creative way to do this, but here's a solution using the `dplyr` package for R.

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(B$Class, function(x) {
  mask <- B$Class == x
  data.frame(Class = x, 
             Students = unlist(strsplit(B$Students[mask], ',')),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  full_join(A, by = 'Students') %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarize(`Mean Score` = mean(Test.Score)) %>%
  full_join(B, by = 'Class')
```

## Step by Step

The `dplyr` package helps with the data manipulation. Here's a reproducible example.

```
library(dplyr)

A <- read.csv(text = 'Students,Test Score
A,  100
B,   81
C,   92
D,   88', stringsAsFactors = F)

B <- read.csv(text = 'Class, Students
1,"{A,D}"
2,"{B,C}"', stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(Students = gsub('\\{|\\}', '', Students))

str(A)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Students  : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
#  $ Test.Score: int  100 81 92 88

str(B)
# 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Class   : int  1 2
#  $ Students: chr  "A,D" "B,C"
```

Do some character manipulation to convert your B table into a "long" format.

```
C <- lapply(B$Class, function(x) {
  mask <- B$Class == x
  data.frame(Class = x, 
             Students = unlist(strsplit(B$Students[mask], ',')),
             stringsAsFactors = F)
}) %>%
  bind_rows()

str(C)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ Class   : int  1 1 2 2
#  $ Students: chr  "A" "D" "B" "C"
```

Add the students' grades to our "long" table.

```
D <- full_join(A, C, by = 'Students')

str(D)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Students  : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
#  $ Test.Score: int  100 81 92 88
#  $ Class     : int  1 2 2 1
```

Group the students by their class and calculate the mean for each class. Then, add a column back in that includes which students are in the class.

```
E <- D %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarize(`Mean Score` = mean(Test.Score)) %>%
  full_join(B, by = 'Class')

str(E)
# Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Class     : int  1 2
#  $ Mean Score: num  94 86.5
#  $ Students  : chr  "A,D" "B,C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution from `dplyr` and `tidyr`. The `separate_rows` function can separate the character in a row. `data_frame` is a function similar to `data.frame`, but it does not coerce character column into factor.

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Create example data frames
df1 <- data_frame(Students = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  `Test Score` = c(100, 81, 92, 88))

df2 <- data_frame(Class = c(1, 2),
                  Students = c("{A,D}", "{B,C}"))

# Create the output
df3 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Students = gsub("\\{|\\}", "", Students)) %>%
  separate_rows(Students) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = "Students") %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(`Mean Score` = mean(`Test Score`)) %>%
  right_join(df2, by = "Class") %>%
  select(Class, Students, `Mean Score`)

df3
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  Class Students `Mean Score`
  <dbl>    <chr>        <dbl>
1     1    {A,D}         94.0
2     2    {B,C}         86.5
```